# Jinja change variable value in IF condition

Tags: flask, jinja2

I need to create a table one row  and one row

so I wrote following code in template file ;

```
      {% for dict_item in sonuc %}

        {% if dict_item.status ==0 %}
            {% if count == 1 %}
        <tr>
            {% set count = 0 %}
            {% elif count == 0 %}
                   <tr class="alt">
                  {% set count = 1 %}
            {% endif %}
        <td>{{ dict_item.zaman }}</td><td>{{ dict_item.saat }}</td><td>{{ dict_item.kad }}</td><td>{{ dict_item.mak }}</td><td>{{ dict_item.uyg }}</td> </tr>
        {% elif dict_item.status ==1 %}
           {% if count == 1 %}
        <tr>
            {% set count = 0 %}
           {% elif count == 0 %}
            <tr class="alt">
            {% set count = 1 %}
        {% endif %}
        <td><b>{{ dict_item.zaman }}</b></td><td><b>{{ dict_item.saat }}</b></td><td><b>{{ dict_item.kad }}</b></td><td><b>{{ dict_item.mak }}</b></td><td><font color="red"><b>{{ dict_item.uyg }}</b></font></td> </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

but not change count value so all rows created with

```
<tr class="alt"> tag
```

as I think I 'm choose the wrong method for solution
I don't understand why I can't change the value of the" content " variable in if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jinja2 `cycle` method is what you're looking for. There's an example [in the docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/tricks/#alternating-rows). Note that one of the values in the cycle arguments can be an empty string.